# Integrating basic equation

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

In the following question I am just wondering if there is another way to solve this integral without using partial fraction decomposition.

$$\int \frac{1}{x(2-x)}dx$$

If there is another way what is it called?

Answer (score 3):

We can also complete the square. We see $$\frac{1}{x(2-x)}= \frac{1}{2x-x^2}= \frac{1}{1-(x-1)^2}.$$ Thus, the integral becomes

$$\int \frac{1}{1-(x-1)^2} \ dx = \tanh^{-1}(x-1) + C.$$

Comment: This is different than the solution I worked out via partial fractions

Comment: @jh123 and that can sometimes happen when using different approaches to a problem.  Both can be correct and both appear different, but in the case that they are both correct that simply implies that the two solutions differ only by a constant.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer and that helpful comment

Comment: @jh123 note that $\tanh^{-1}(x)=\frac 12\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ so $\tanh^{-1}(x-1)=\frac 12\ln(\frac{x}{2-x})=\frac 12\ln(x)-\frac 12\ln(2-x)$ which is the result obtained by partial fractions.

Comment: @zwim thanks for that comment, I should touch up on my trig identities for future questions